# How do I list just the files that would be committed?

Tags: git, file, commit, status

Is there any way to get a list of files that will be committed when I type the following?

```
git commit -m "my changes"
```

git status lists too much.  I could strip out all the words, but I'd rather not.  And I don't want to be told about untracked files.

I've tried

```
git ls-files -md
```

but that doesn't show files that have been recently added, but not yet committed.

I'm looking for the same output you'd get from

```
svn status -q
```

For example
$ svn status -q
A       file.py
M       dir/database.py
M       start.py

Answer (score 55):

This is what I was looking for.  Thanks to notnoop for the lead I needed.  I wanted to post back my solution in case it helps others.

```
git diff HEAD  --name-only
```

Since I intended to do

```
git commit -s -F mesage.txt
```

with the files found in the first line.

My intent is to create a little system that totally ignores the index i.e. that I never need to do git add.  (From what I understand, the index is useful when creating patches, which isn't by no means the norm in my workflow.)

Comment: don't you mean `git diff --cached  --name-only`? the `diff HEAD` will show the files last committed and not pushed. the `--cached` one will show files that will be committed when you run `git commit`

Comment: `git diff --staged --name-only` also works.  Depending upon how you think about git you may want to use --staged [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39877896) instead of --cached.

Answer (score 15):

This command will tell you what files in your index/cache/staging area differ from the current HEAD (and whether they are additions, modifications or deletions) which is the changes which will be committed if you use `git commit` without explicit paths or the `-a` option. It's format is reasonably similar to the `svn status` output which you show.

```
git diff --cached --name-status
```

Answer (score 6):

I know OP original asked to avoid `git status`, but I felt this would be nice to leave for posterity (i.e other people who don't share OP's reservations).

```
git status --porcelain | grep -v '^[ |??]' | sed -e 's/[A-Z] *//'
```

My reasoning is that `git status --porcelain` seems like it was built for exactly this type of quandary...

source: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status.html

EDIT:
You may chose to not use `sed -e 's/[A-Z] *//'` if you wish to keep git's modification tags in front of each file name.

Comment: +1. I agree that `git status --porcelain` can be used in a script. I have documented as much in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309, saying that "The new option \[`--porcelain`\] makes the command's native output format to emit output that is easier to handle by Porcelain."

Comment: This does not seem to list the actual files that would be pushed during a git push (and that have been staged by a git add/commmit)

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
git diff --name-status
```

I get the following:

```
$ git diff --name-status
M       README.markdown
```

Without the untracked files.

Comment: This isn't correct. The question is, "what will be commited when I say `git commit -m message`". This gives the differences between the work tree and the cache which is closer to what *won't* be committed.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be useful `git diff HEAD --compact-summary`

From the documentation : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---compact-summary

`Output a condensed summary of extended header information such as file creations or deletions ("new" or "gone", optionally "+l" if it’s a symlink) and mode changes ("+x" or "-x" for adding or removing executable bit respectively) in diffstat. The information is put between the filename part and the graph part. Implies --stat.`

This seems to be very close to the svn example mentioned in the question.