# git diff: what is the difference between --cached and --staged

Tags: git, git-diff

To compare the staged with the last commit:

```
git diff --cached
git diff --staged
```

Both commands generate the same results, right?

Comment: With due respect to all the answers, I'd still recommend to read the `gitcli` manual page (run `git help cli` to get it displayed) which explains how these options differ *where they differ.* It's a lesser-known fact of Git -- that it's actually shipped with a set of documentation pages which explain the terminology, the basics, and even feature a tutorial and explanation of a set of common workflows. You can start with `git help git` ;-)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The documentation for `git diff` says "`--staged` is a synonym of `--cached`", so yes.

Answer (score 10):

From the docs - --staged is a synonym of --cached

Answer (score 8):

[git-scm.com/docs/git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) (see bolded text):

> `git diff [<options>] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>…​]`
>
> This form is to view the changes you staged for the next commit relative to the named `<commit>`. Typically you would want comparison with the latest commit, so if you do not give , it defaults to HEAD. If HEAD does not exist (e.g. unborn branches) and  is not given, it shows all staged changes. **--staged is a synonym of --cached**.