# git status -s show only files to be commited

Tags: git

I've about twenty C# repositories, where I'm updating NuGet references with some PowerShell magic.

I know that `git status -s` returns a list of files that were modified. Does `git status` offer a switch where it only lists that were added to the index and therefore are going to be committed (in `short` format).

I found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814504/how-do-i-list-just-the-files-that-would-be-committed) answer, which is from 2009. The answer says I've to use `git diff` for that job.

However, since the answer is ten years old, I wanted to know if there is now a way of using `git status -s` with the actual Git version (=`2.21.0`).

Thanks.

Comment: Those old questions tend to get updated answers when they're that popular. If there was a new way it would probably be there.

Comment: Ok, thx. Then I'm going to close my question.

Answer (score -1):

`git status` 
will show your all modified files which you have to committed.

Comment: I know but I want it in combination with the short form (= `git status -s`)

Comment: This answer doesn't offer anything that wasn't obviously understood by the OP.